# Elements of the ring of residue class ($\mod m$)

Tags: group-theory

I have trouble finding the elements of $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_5$. Any help is appreciated.
$\mathbb Z_{10} = \{0,1,\dots,9\}$.

Comment: $\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_5\cong\Bbb Z_{10}$

Comment: I have trouble understanding why you mention $Z^*_{10}$. I don't see how it has any connection to finding the product of two cycle groups.

Comment: My goal is to show that Z10 is isomorphic to Z2 x Z5.

Comment: @Kay, change your question to reflect your goal.

Answer (score 0):

In base $5$, the numbers $0,1,\dots,9$ can be written $00,01,02,03,04,10,11,12,13,14$, that is, $ab$, with $a=0,1$ and $b=0,1,2,3,4$. This gives an isomorphism $\Bbb Z_{10}\cong\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_5$.

Explicitly, $(a,b) \mapsto 5a+b$ is an isomorphism $\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_5 \to \Bbb Z_{10}$.